# how to add a selected string array from many string arrays to spinner?

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I have these following string arrays:-

```
<string-array name="subject_CS_2">
    <item>Eng. Physics</item>
    <item>Eng. Chemistry</item>
    <item>Eng. Math</item>
    <item>Communicative tech.</item>
    <item>Mechanics</item>
    <item>C</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="subject_CS_3">
    <item>Mathematics</item>
    <item>EDC</item>
    <item>DSA</item>
    <item>OOPs</item>
    <item>DE</item>
    <item>FLSP</item>
</string-array>
```

how to set selected array to spinner from given array at run time.

Comment: Will you give the user an option to select the array?

Comment: Check my answer, is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
  Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinnerId);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array. subject_CS_2,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```